# How to separate an element from ng-repeat to link to another url?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have html code in angularjs as

```
<li ng-show="subCategory.status =='Active' || subCategory.status =='active'"
    ng-repeat="subCategory in subCategories">

    <a href="">
       <strong ng-click="addDetails(subCategory)">
           {{subCategory.subcategory}}
       </strong>
    </a> 

    <br>

</li>
```

`subCategory in subCategories` are linked to url inside `addDetails(subCategory)` function.

For one of the elements in ng-repeat, I like to link to another separate url.
How can I do that?

Comment: for what element and what are the conditions for that? please specify

Comment: that you should do part of your javascript code... rule of thumb: custom logic should go in js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ui-router

```
    ui-sref=details({id:subCategory.subcategory})
```

in config

```
    .state('details',{
                        url:'/details/:id',
                        templateUrl:'details.html'
```

And get it

```
myApp.controller('DetailController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams){
     $scope.message = "Your ID is " + $stateParams.id;
```

Or if you use ngroute

```
myApp.controller('DetailController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams){
     $scope.message = "Your ID is " + $routeParams.id;
```